# What is an alternative for ginger?

Tags: substitutions, ginger

Some people don't like ginger taste in meal.  What can I use instead of ginger?
Actually I want to cook cauliflower, so what can I use instead of ginger.

Comment: Unless you're making something with 'ginger' in its name, you can probably leave it out.

Comment: Marosh: welcome to Seasoned Advice?  In order for people to help you, you'll need to share what dish(es) you are trying to make with no ginger (preferably with a link to a similar recipe), and what your guests' objections to it are (for example, do they hate all strong spices?)

Comment: What are the benefits you'd like? A tasty dish? On topic, and use other spices. Health? Off topic; they're debatable anyway and we're not qualified to answer so will have to close the question.  I suspect that latter but will hold off voting to close to give you a chance to address this comment

Comment: @ChrisH I have been poring over this question too. Making a tasty dish is in principle on topic, but in this particular case, I am afraid it ends up being a too-broad pairing question (people will start suggesting randomn other spices which go with cauliflower). So I am hard pressed to come up with an interpretation which is not closeable.

Comment: @rumtscho one general answer could be: omit the ginger, increase all other spices by a pinch.  Another could be: add chilli if you want a kick. It depends  what the OP is trying to do with the cauliflower. I'm not keen on cauliflower so I couldn't address the pairing, preferring to overpower it, thus I don't see it as a pairing question.  It will probably end up closed, but I prefer to give the benefit of the doubt for a few hours especially for newish users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something with a sharp, bright flavor. Maybe garlic, shallot, or horseradish.

Answer (score 1):

if you are making couliflower then you can use garlic instead of ginger,and in some other dishes as you say about meal you can use ground nutmeg,cinnamon etc.